# Poor performance of cartesian controller in the x direction on pr2

Tags: ros, microcontroller, pr2, cartesian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone.

I am using [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/robot_mechanism_controllers/JTCartesian%20Controller) controller for pr2 arm control, with the example configuration. The arm moves quite well in y and z direction, but does really poorly in x direction (approaching/leaving the robot body), which means that it can only reach some specific points, but cannot move continuously in this direction. I tried to adjust some parameters, and it turns out that the arm can move continuously, but when I want it to move along x axis, its y and z positions also change severely.

The thing is that I do not really care about the orientation of the end effector, and it seems that the capability of moving continuously in x direction depends on the commanded orientation. I wonder if there is some parameter I can adjust to address the position error and ignore the orientation error. I would also appreciate it if someone suggests a better cartesian controller. Thanks.

Nan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36824/poor-performance-of-cartesian-controller-in-the-x-direction-on-pr2/) by [Nan Jiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/2653/nan-jiang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 131 on 2012-06-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OK I have figured it out. The thing is that I have set the goal position in a wrong scale... so that it tries to reach positions that are far away from its body. That's why y and z directions work well but x does not. Hope it helps if anyone encounters the same problem.

---

Originally posted by [Nan Jiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/2653/nan-jiang/) with karma: 131 on 2012-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0